# AJAX: Accessing elements of a returned List

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a user interface where a user can search for a user+email. This request is sent to my Spring MVC Controller and this returns an `AjaxResponseBody` object.
This object has the fields `message`, `code` and a list of `users`.

The Browser also receives this data but I cannot acceess this list somehow. I tried several approaches by iterating over the JSON response but with no success.

I want to directly access the key "result" in the JSON response as you can see the in the picture below my question and work with the list elements. Moreover I want to display the whole returned list at once in **one** alert box.

JS:

```
function searchViaAjax() {

    var search = {};
    search["username"] = $("#username").val();
    search["email"] = $("#email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "search/api/getSearchResult",
        data: JSON.stringify(search),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display("SUCCESS");
            for (var i in data){ 
               alert(i); //attempt to iterate over the items.
            }
            jQuery.each(function (key, value) {
                alert(key, value); //second attempt to iterate over the items.
            })
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display("ERROR");
            //display(2);
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            display("DONE");
            enableSearchButton(true);
        }
    });
}
```

AjaxResponseBody class

```
@ResponseBody
public class AjaxResponseBody {

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String msg;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    String code;
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    List<User> result;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public List<User> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<User> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AjaxResponseResult [msg=" + msg + ", code=" + code + ", result=" + result + "]";
    }    
}
```

Reponse

[image]

Comment: you can simply use 
data.result.map(function(v,i){
    console.log(v,i);
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to iterate over data.result like

```
resultObj = data.result
 for (var i in resultObj ){ 
   alert(resultObj[i].email, resultObj[i].username, resultObj [i].phone); 
 }
```

Comment: Ty. But this displays now only "0" in the alert window.
I tried with a combination of your solution like:
for (var i in data.result[0]) {
                alert(i);
            }
This shows now the keys but not they values. I would like to have the whole list with key+value displayed in one alert box

Comment: that displays now "undefinied"

Comment: please check now

Comment: the alert is not displaying all values but it brought me to the right path.